# "Update cannot be an iterator block" when trying to wait for jump to finish

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation

As of now, I'm getting a C# error (CS1624) stating that:

> The body of PlayerMovement.Update() cannot be an iterator block because void is not an iterator interface type.

The error is within the `void Update section`. I believe it started when I added lines 34 - 37, the second "if" clause.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    Animator m_Animator;
    bool m_Jump;

    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;

    void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", true);
        }

        // These are lines 34-37 that cause the error, I think.    
        if (m_Animator.GetBool("Jump") == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", false);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);` won't work as the error says. And you do not want your update to pause for 3sec in the first place, your whole Character would stop responsding.

Comment: I think you can either keep a float variable to use as a timer, which decreases by Time.deltaTime every frame, and when it elapses you can set your bool to false. yield return [something] only works within a Coroutine but I don't know if you'd want that in this scenario. If you are curious about it, I'd suggest you read the Unity documentation about Coroutines or checkout DMGregory's answer on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/189246/how-to-add-time-delay-in-unity-c/189248?noredirect=1#comment342654_189248

Answer (score 1):

When you want a method that can pause its execution and resume later in Unity, that's called a Coroutine, and it needs to be set up in a specific way. The return type has to be `IEnumerator`, not `void`.

That's why the compiler complains when you try to put a `yield return` statement inside a `void Update` - "`void`" is not a type that can be used as an iterator, which is what Unity's coroutines are built on.

If you change the return type to `IEnumerator`, Unity will tell you that the `Update` method is forbidden from being used as a coroutine. But that's OK, we can start our own named whatever we like.

Here's a version of your script with working syntax:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    Animator m_Animator;
    bool m_Jump;

    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;

    void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Start our coroutine when the MonoBehaviour activates.
        StartCoroutine(JumpPoll());
    }

    IEnumerator JumpPoll()
    {
        while(true) {
            // If you don't want to lock horizontal input while jumping,
            // then move this line into FixedUpdate. It's OK to read axes there.
            horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                jump = true;
                m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", true);

                // Pause this loop for 3 seconds while the rest of the game proceeds.
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", false);
            }
            // Let the game run one frame, 
            // and resume next frame just like Update() does.
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Time.deltaTime automatically returns fixedDeltaTime
        // when accessed from FixedUpdate, so it's good to just use that
        // (less risk of errors when moving code or calling it from other places).
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.deltaTime, false, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution but for other wait operations you might want to use a `Coroutine`. `Invoke` is not a real timer or counter but the second parameter allows you to specify the time amount when the call should be executed. In this case the function `ResetJump` will run 3 seconds later and reset your jump.

```
void Update() {
    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
    if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) && (jump == false))
    {
        jump = true;
        m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", true);
        Invoke("ResetJump", 3f);
    }
}

private void ResetJump() {
    jump = false;
    m_Animator.SetBool("Jump", false);
}
```